# How to get all Connected Clients of Redis Cluster?

Tags: redis, redisson

How to get all connected clients of a redis cluster?
I am using AWS elasticCache redis with non cluster mode and redission as my redis client.
My Use Case:
I need to run specific code from only 1 connected redis client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

redis has command about client information like `CLIENT LIST`, check out [this page](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) .

you could checkout [this page](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/10.-additional-features#105-low-level-redis-client) for the command redisson has not supported yet.

Comment: I checked that command but there is no similar api in Redisson client. 
**Redisson wiki page:** https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/11.-Redis-commands-mapping.